# Error Installation Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I installed visual studio 2013 Ultimate Edition, I got error

.NET Framework 4.5.1
Asia

Bet when I installed .NET framework 4.5.1, my windows 8.1 said that it's already intalled.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO this is a misleading error info - I had this error when there was not enought free space on disc...

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, there is a bug when downloading and using the ISO image. The web installer is preferred. This does of course make it harder to put it on a flash drive, which is unfortunate. Tee article is also about installing on a Windows 8.1 machine, while I'm using Windows 7 Professional. However, I expect that the issue is the same.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe3d5411-b601-425e-bf44-8cf5cd00f7af/visual-studio-2013-setup-failed-when-installing-on-windows-81-preview?forum=vssetup

Please bear in mind that the ISO installer leaves a lot of stuff behind when it fails - you need to uninstall it all and reboot before trying the web installer